# How do I render a prop which is actually a component?

Tags: reactjs, routes

I have a subcomponent that I need to behave as if it is rendered. I want this subcomponent's functions to be called **before** it is rendered (i.e componentDidMount, constructor etc)

To achieve that, I'm passing this subcomponent to a `<CustomRoute />` component, which, based on certain conditions will either

1. Render the subcomponent directly, OR
2. Render something else

Either way, I need the `subcomponent` functions called before hand. I'm planning to accomplish this in the subcomponent as follows

```
render() {
   if(this.props.someCondition) render "";
    render <div>Actual Subcomponent</div>
}
```

I have my `CustomRoute` set up as follows

```
// App.js
import subcomponent from "./somewhere"
import CustomRoute from "./CustomRoute"
Class App.js extends React {
   render() {
    return <div>
     <CustomRoute path='/subcomponent' component={subcomponent} isPreloaded={true}/>
    </div>
   }
}
```

**The question is about how to implement the CustomRoute**

```
import Route from "react-router-dom"
class CustomRoute extends React {
  render() {
    if(this.props.isPreloaded) return this.props.component; // Is this right?
    return <Route component={this.props.component} />
  }
}
```

The TL;DR version of this question would be

**How do I render a component that is brought in as a prop instead of an import?**

Comment: a quick demo about this for your reference... https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-nobel-4veoi

Comment: add tags `if(this.props.isPreloaded) return <this.props.component />`

Answer (score 0):

- change the `subcomponent`  to `Subcomponent` at import

  ```
  import Subcomponent from "./somewhere"
  ```

then pass it like this:

```
   <CustomRoute path='/subcomponent' component={<Subcomponent />} isPreloaded={true}/>
```

- for more check this link:
  [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

Comment: What is the implementation inside <CustomRoute /> going to be like? CustomRoute has no idea what the component's name is.

Comment: I think your `CustomRoute` correct, if it didn't work, check the console for error and let me know

Comment: I got this

./src/ui/components/CustomRoutes/CustomRoute.js
  Line 17:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

The technique you are looking for is officially labelled [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

**Explanation**

While in most cases render props are associated with functional components, you can apply the same concept to class components as well with a minor tweak.

In a pure JS world the react components can be thought of as just functions. A functional component is a pure JS function whereas a class component is a constructor function.

Hence passing these in the props to a parent component `CustomRoute` you effectively get those functions in the props.

All you need to do is trick react into believing that these are actually React components and not just any functions by using the magical angular braces (<>)

Here's your CustomRoute:

```
import Route from "react-router-dom"

class CustomRoute extends React {
  render() {
    const SubComponent = this.props.component; // It doesn't matter if the passed component is a functional or a class component.
    if(this.props.isPreloaded) return <SubComponent />
    return <Route component={this.props.component} />
  }
}
```